# Persist mouseenter/mouseleave on parent element

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, mouseleave

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class='sub_menu a'></div>
    <div class='sub_menu b'></div>
    <div class='sub_menu c'></div>
    <ul>
        <li class='a'>link a</li>
        <li class='b'>link b</li>
        <li class='c'>link c</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```javascript
$('li').mouseleave(function(e) {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $(".sub_menu." + cl).show();
}).mouseleave(function() {
    var cl = $(this).attr('class');
    $(".sub_menu." + cl).hide(); //
});
```

On mouseenter on each `<li>`  the div `sub_menu` with same class (a, b or c)  will show up.
I need that when the mouseleaves the `<li>` but is over the opened div, this div will remain open.

Now when I go with mouse over sub_menu, this will close up. I hope you understand what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li').hover(function() {
   $(".sub_menu").hide();

   var cl = $(this).attr('class');
   $(".sub_menu." + cl).show();
});​
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/8y5Zh/1/

Comment: When i go with mouse on opened sub_menu this will hide!!

Comment: Ok. now its possible hide sub_menu when i leave <li>?

Comment: Only this idea here: http://jsfiddle.net/8y5Zh/2/. It handles mouse leave on the parent container.